# Plugins wont work with vb.net express

Tags: .net, visual-studio, add-in

What won't plugins wont work with vb c# studio express?

Answer (score 7):

The Express editions do not support Visual Studio Addins.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft doesn't want to allow users to replace all the Standard+ functionality in Visual Studio when using the Express editions, as that would be akin to starving themselves. So, the decision was made that plugins would not be supported in the Express editions.

If there are plugins you can't live without, buying a license for the Standard edition isn't too much money, and they almost always give away free copies of standard at launch events for new versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to make addins in the express editions, but it's not worth Microsoft wrath. That's what happened with [TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/). Why don't you just get the professional edition of VB.NET? If cost is an issue, you could try having one of your buddies still at the Uni, buy an academic version.

You could also try using [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/). It comes with a lot of useful addins.

Answer (score 0):

Students qualify for [free Microsoft software](https://downloads.channel8.msdn.com/), which include Visual Studio Pro.